# Why got Firebug removed after updating Firefox to version 50?

Tags: firefox, firebug

After updating Firefox to version 50.0 my Firebug opens the default developer tools. The original Firebug doesn't work anymore.

I have always preferred Firebug as my default debugging tool. I want the original Firebug back in Firefox 50. How can I do that?

Comment: In Firefox 50, Firebug will not work even after making it default, Script tab will not be able to debug

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebug is not working on Mozilla version 52](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42834636/firebug-is-not-working-on-mozilla-version-52)

Comment: @Stewart, I think which question you have described here it is the duplicate of my question. Because I have asked first this question. My question is 10months old and which you have attached is 6 months old :)

Comment: @NikunjChotaliya Oops. I looked and saw "Mar 16", which my brain read as "Mar 2016"!

Comment: @Stewart Ok Np but kindly close duplicate question request which you have raised.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Firebug does not work anymore once [multi-process Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox) (separate processes for the Firefox UI and the websites) is enabled. See the [related post in the Firebug blog](https://blog.getfirebug.com/2016/06/07/unifying-firebug-firefox-devtools/).

You may be able to reenable Firebug by setting the preferences `browser.tabs.remote.autostart`, `browser.tabs.remote.autostart.1` and `browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2` to false via `about:config`. Though at some point this preference will be removed.

So, you are advised to use the [Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) instead. I am writing a [migration guide on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Migrating_from_Firebug). Firebug features that are not in the DevTools are covered in a [Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=991806).

Comment: Firefox's DevTools are terrible compared to Firebug. They're so slow and clunky and not as user-friendly.

Comment: I also loved Firebug and I agree that the Firefox DevTools are still feeling slow, though I can't change the situation. I'm just trying to help Firebug users with the migration.

Comment: Of course. I managed to get it working by starting afresh and installing both Firebug and Firequery. I think its Firequery thats forcing Firebug to work

Comment: Good to hear! Though, as I said above, that may work for now, though at some point multi-process Firefox is enforced and at the latest at this moment it won't work anymore.

Comment: Volume ones answer worked for me.  For some reason after installing Firequery Firebug started working.

Comment: Firebug is working here except for the Javascript tab "No Javascript on this page". Tried all options mentioned here, even uninstall with deleting the folder in AppData and the autostart options. Nu luck. Do you guys have Javascript working? Or also only the other tabs?

Comment: The *Script* panel is indeed not working anymore since Firefox 50, which I [mentioned in another thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40885076/432681) and there is no way to reenable it that I know of. Though note that Firebug is not maintained anymore, so with one of the upcoming Firefox versions it will definitely break. So again, you should really switch to the Firefox DevTools. And [I got promised by the team behind them](https://bugzil.la/991806#c15) that the most pressing gaps to Firebug will be prioritized.

Comment: Firefox devTool don't persist debug point after refreshing page
2. don't search the body text in response.
3. Debug hangs frequently

Comment: @SebastianZartner How can I use the Console and the Run query horizontally. This was possible in Firebug. Previously console output will be in the leftside and run window will be on the rightside. Can the same be achieved in the new dev tools? This now looks like chrome devtools. You need to restart your browser for this settings to work. Please add this to the answer.

Comment: @Lucky I [answered this question in another thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41951925/432681). Regarding the settings, they normally apply immediately. If they don't, you should post a separate question. Both issues are out of the scope of this one.

Comment: @SebastianZartner No mater how many migration guide you write, none of them can replace firebug.

Comment: @ClainDsilva True, I also miss Firebug. Firebug is history now, though, and the only thing we can do is try to push the other DevTools to adopt its features and improve their UI to work as smooth as Firebug did.

Answer (score 7):

First remove new version of "firebug" and download old version of  "Firebug(2.0.17)" from following URL:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/versions/

Comment: any possibility to install Firebug now?

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall Firefox completely including deleting the Mozilla folder within your APPDATA.

Then reinstall Firefox and add both Firebug and FireQuery.

After that everything should work as before.

Comment: First of all thanks for the give your time to answer my question but I don't think it's proper solution to uninstall firefox and deleting all data. Also Sebastian already answered of my question and it's work perfect for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can also go on Help -> Troubleshooting Information -> Refresh Firefox and install Firebug through http://addons.mozilla.org/

Answer (score 0):

For all the folks out there, there is a good news..!! Firebug works great on these two Mozilla based browsers.

**[Cyberfox](https://cyberfox.8pecxstudios.com/) & [Palemoon](https://www.palemoon.org)**

Both are forks of forefox that uses code before the implementation multi-process. Cyberfox uses the more recent code fork compared to Palemoon.

Both browsers are well maintained and updated regularly.

Cyberfox announced its death on March 2017 but its still actively maintained [as of Dec 2017] and I still get update.

Both browsers support cross platform windows / Linux, on Linux you should have 64 bit distro to use cyberfox. Palemoon on the other hand works great on both the bits.

[image: Latest CyberFox running firebug]

[image: Palemoon running firebug]