# How to activate multi-line command line in Firefox DevTools?

Tags: firefox, command-line, firefox-developer-tools

[image: Firefox DevTools console]

How to make the console of the Firefox DevTools multi-line?
I am aware of the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> keyboard shortcut, which makes the command line go to the next line. Though like in Firebug, I want to vertically separate my console into command line and results part, but I can not find that functionality.

Comment: Your screenshot actually shows the Firefox DevTools with the Firebug theme, not Firebug. See the [related Mozilla blog post](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/).

Comment: I've edited your question now to reflect that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can try the `scratchpad`.  Go to `Settings >> Available Toolbox Buttons` and `check` the box for `scratchpad`.  Refer the `screenshot`:

[image]

Once done, you'll have a `notepad-like` icon in your `developer console navigation bar` on the right side...[image].  Click on it and it will open a `scratch pad` on which you can write `code` and `execute`...

[image]

Good Luck.

Answer (score 13):

**Firefox Developer version(v70)** has multiline console which can be activated with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> (on linux at least, I havent found the shortcut in the offical docs). So this will soon show up in mainline FF i guess.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and ctrl+b worked for me.

Comment: this is available from Firefox v71 onwards. Simply there is a little icon in the bottom of the dev tools to switch to multiline editor.

Comment: `Cmd`+`b` on macOS also works to toggle this. Handy to know the keyboard shortcut (`ctl`/`cmd`+`b`) because the little icon does _not_ appear in the multiline editor, if you want to go back to in-line.

Answer (score 5):

The command line the Firefox DevTools has a "smart multi-line" feature. That means it detects when a command is not finished and automatically inserts a line break, e.g. when you write `document.` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. As you mentioned, you can also insert a line break manually by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The DevTools also offer a completely separate command editor panel called [Scratchpad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Scratchpad), which you can enable via the [settings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Settings) (under the Default Developer Tools* section).

There is currently no multi-line editor as a side panel like Firebug's [Command Editor](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Editor), but it is [already requested](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1133849).

This is also [described in the migration guide for Firebug users](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Migrating_from_Firebug#Multi-line_command_line).

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a modern answer, so:

To enter multi-line console mode, click the button at far right, or press Ctrl+B:

[image]

To go back to single-line console mode, click the cross at the top right of the editor, or press Ctrl+B:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hello when in firefox browser laptop/pc developer tools console or

via remote debugging firefox browser laptop/pc developer tools console

icon for x to close multi line console mode and switch to normal console mode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDz3h.png)

To Toggle between firefox normal console mode and multi line console mode
when on console ( developer tools ) window

- enter ctrl+b to switch from normal console mode to multi line console
  mode
- enter x button when on multi line console mode to switch to normal
  console mode

To Toggle between firefox normal console mode and multi line console mode
when on console ( developer tools ) window

- enter ctrl+b to switch from normal console mode to multi line console
  mode
- enter ctrl+b to switch from multi line console mode to normal console
  mode

icon for  multi line console mode highlighted in red
this looks like book like form to click on it so enters multi line console mode from normal console mode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pxra.png)