# Why my firefox Responsive Design Mode view doesn't look like it does in MDN?

Tags: firefox, responsive, firefox-developer-tools

I don't know why my firefox Responsive Design Mode view doesn't look like it is presented in MDN ?

MDN view:

[image]

My view:

[image]

I am using firefox 53.0.2 on PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (at least) two preferences controlling whether the old Responsive Design Mode UI or the new one is shown:

- `devtools.responsive.html.enabled` needs to be set to `true` => Directly controls whether the reworked UI is displayed.
- `browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2` needs to be set to `true` => Controls whether [multi-process Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox) is enabled and the new RDM UI obviously doesn't work in single-process Firefox instances.
  To check whether the multi-process mode is enabled, go to `about:support` and ensure that the value at "Multiprocess Windows" says "Enabled".

Those preferences can be changed via [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config).

*Note: Once you enable the multi-process setting, [add-ons that don't support this feature like e.g. Firebug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40748127/432681) won't work anymore.*

Comment: thanks a lot, your answer was really helpful. I added some details that solved my problem for people that are facing the same issue.

Comment: Where did you add details?  I am unable to get this to work using those settings.

Comment: I've updated my answer now saying that you should check `about:support` for whether multi-process mode is enabled.