# Firebug is not updated

Tags: firefox, firebug

I try to use this: https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/firebug/ but it isn't updated for weeks.

I want to use Firefox, as it's open source. Is there a Firebug alternative? Or what's the easiest way to add Firebug to the latest Firefox?

Comment: Firebug is no longer being developed. You can use [firefox dev tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why got Firebug removed after updating Firefox to version 50?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40744448/why-got-firebug-removed-after-updating-firefox-to-version-50)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebug is [officially discontinued](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/) for several years now. E.g. there's an [announcement from 2015](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/10/firebug-devtools-integration/).

The main reasons for Firebug not being continued is that internal changes in Firefox for better stability and performance, namely [separated processes for the browser's UI and the web contents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox) and [restricting add-on support to cross-browser compatible WebExtensions](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2016/11/23/add-ons-in-2017/), would have required to rewrite the majority of its code and would have it's feature set due to a limited API.

Mozilla suggests to use the [Firefox Developer Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) instead, which are built into Firefox and can be opened via <kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> or via the Firefox Menu > *Web Developer* > *Toggle Tools*.

Note that like Firefox, those tools are open source. Their code is partly hosted on a [Mozilla repository](http://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/devtools) and partly on a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/devtools-html).