# if firebug does not saupport to install firefox, This add-on is not compatible with your version of Firefox

Tags: firebug

When I download firefox 23-8-2017 , I go to add-ones  option and search firebug. But when i click firebug icon, i see

> "This add-on is not compatible with your version of Firefox. "

What should I do to add firebug successfully?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebug is not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45793270/firebug-is-not-updated)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall firefox
Go the this link
https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/
and install this version 54.0/
now install firebug 
now you can update firefox with working firebug

Comment: where should I go   win64 or win64-EME-free

Comment: Here is the direct download link for you
https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/54.0/win64/en-US/

let me know if it works for you

Comment: **does above thing is Helpful?**